# Pandas find unique entries per row, ignoring a specific number

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a simple data set that I have stored in pandas as dataframe. I have tried per row to measure the number of unique entries, ignoring though the -1 number if it shows up.

Below the appended column to the dataframe
[image]

...

[image]

I am adding this column by doing

```py
pdSequences['unique']=pdSequences.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)
```

but as you can see the code does not work correctly always. The first row returns correctly that unique is four (ignoring the last two -1s).

If you see though row 28, I wanted to get back 5 but the code returns 6.

Can you help me understand why I get these two different type of behavior and how I can count unique entries (but ignoring -1)?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Please, provide data in text format, not picture. We don't want to type all your data by hand. Thank you ! Can you also provide the expected output ?

Comment: The behaviour is correct, there are 4 unique numbers in the first row (58, 68, 59, -1)

Comment: If you want to ignore `-1`, then the amount of unique values on row 1 is 3: `58, 68, 59`. If you provide some sample data (not in a picture) we can reproduce an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
a[a!=-1].nunique(axis=1)
```

to ignore exact `-1` values, or

```
a[a>-1].nunique(axis=1)
```

to ignore any negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently simply computes the number of unique entries per row, because you are not doing anything to ignore -1. This is how you can do this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'0':[58, 59, 60],
                 '1':[58, 60, -1],
                 '2':[-1, 61, -1]})
def myfunc(row):
    if -1 in row.values:
        return row.nunique() - 1
    else:
        return row.nunique()

a['unique'] = a.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
a

     0   1   2  unique
0   58  58  -1  1
1   59  60  61  3
2   60  -1  -1  1
```

Comment: This doesn't work for an arbitrary number of `-1` per row.

Comment: Yes it does. On what input do you think this doesn't work? My test dataframe has 0, 1 and 2 of -1 per row and it works every time.

Comment: Try it with three or more `-1` per row.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused... yes it does indeed work correctly. :-)